# How do I adjust this code which sorts a single sheet so that it sorts multiple sheets in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I'm running a macro which takes data from one sheet and copies into several other worksheets. I want to adjust the following code so that I can sort ALL worksheets in my workbook by Column Q once it's been copied and not just the sheet named "Sorted1"

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sorted1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sorted1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=range("D2:D" & lastrow _
), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sorted1").Sort
.SetRange range("A1:Q" & lastrow)
.Header = xlYes
.MatchCase = False
.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
.SortMethod = xlPinYin
.Apply
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call sheets not only by their name, but also by their position in your workbook.

```
sheets("sheet1") <- calls sheet named "sheet1"
sheets(1)        <- calls the first sheet
```

If you want your script to iterate through all sheets, you can use a for-loop and replace the sheet-name by the iterative variable.

```
for i = 1 to x 'replace x with number of sheets
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).sort (your script)...
   ....
Next
```

If the number of sheets changes sometimes, use the following command instead of x to count the number of sheets

```
Application.Sheets.Count
```

So:

```
for i = 1 to Application.Sheets.Count
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).sort (your script)...
   ....
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub sortAllSheets()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, LastRow As Long
 Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
 For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
    'if all the columns have the same number of rows, this can be done for all the code
    LastRow = sh.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    sh.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    sh.Sort.SortFields.Add2 key:=sh.Range("D2:D" & LastRow) _
            , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With sh.Sort
        .SetRange sh.Range("A1:Q" & LastRow) 'if LastRow is the same as in D:D
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
 Next
End Sub
```